# Why is the view from my XIB file not being loaded by the UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

In my app delegate, I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[CGMContainerViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I have an unmodified CGMContainerViewController.h/m and a modified CGMContainerViewController.xib (added a button). The view is linked to the File Owner.

Why is the view from the XIB not showing?

EDIT: Is it because I'm trying to load a view with a status bar into the window?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of your code, you aren't loading any XIB files. You need to call **`initWithNibName:`**

```
self.viewController = [[CGMContainerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                       @"CGMContainerViewController" bundle: nil];
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything either. I thought that init tries to load the XIB with the same name anyways.

Comment: This is not required and I often prefer to leave it off or move the decision inside the viewController itself. It's cool to note that `[[CGMContainerViewController alloc] init]` will automatically load a nib called `CGMContainerView`, which I think is more semantically correct that giving it the same name as the viewController

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your File's Owner in the XIB is set to `CGMContainerViewController`

[image]

Comment: I think it is. I'll check later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think it was because for a UINavigationController, you have to set the rootViewController and all the layers. I just changed it to a UIViewController because I didn't really need the navigation, just the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I faced is .If you name your viewController with special character with "-" and some other things your xib will not get loaded
example--> (wrong naming)
view-controller1 (If naming is like this then the xib wont get loaded)
example--->(correct naming)
viewController1 (xib will get loaded)